# Why are my textboxes disappearing with C# / VS2019?

Tags: c#, controls, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

I have worked on a number of C# projects, currently using VS2019. A common issue I have found is that my textboxes (and sometimes buttons/labels) disappear after I build and run an app.

For example, I have the following code in designer (just a snip, not everything obviously):

```
// 
// tbFirstName
// 
Form1.tbFirstName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(243, 183);
Form1.tbFirstName.Name = "tbFirstName";
Form1.tbFirstName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 26);
Form1.tbFirstName.TabIndex = 0;
// 
// tbLastName
// 
Form1.tbLastName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(243, 215);
Form1.tbLastName.Name = "tbLastName";
Form1.tbLastName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 26);
Form1.tbLastName.TabIndex = 1;
```

Normally, it has "this." where I have entered Form1. I moved this into the Form1 class because I needed to use them there, and for storing my data and using it, this just worked for me somehow.

After building and running the code, I notice the textboxes aren't on the screen anymore, I stop the program from running, and I check designer again. This time, the above code (and other textboxes, labels, and datagridviews) are missing. This makes me have to CTRL+Z or CTRL+Y to get them back. Eventually, I am able to get what I need done, but it takes a while having to enter and re-enter my work.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how I can get around it?
Thank you!

Comment: `Form1` looks wrong and I'm surprised it compiles, why *doesn't* it use `this`?

Comment: When I’m using the values from the text boxes in and out of the Form1 class it won’t let me access the values, so I have to move them to the Form1 class and add “public static” so I can access them elsewhere.

Comment: So why don't you use `this.tbLastName` instead of `Form1.tbLastName` then you don't need `static`? `static` completely doens't make sense with `TextBox` on a `Form`

Comment: I wasn’t able to access the values from the text box in a different subclass using ‘this’ when it wasn’t static, I’m not sure why.

Comment: You need `public` not `static`, and you can do that from the designer with `Modifiers` property

Comment: "I wasn’t able to access the values from the text box in a different subclass using ‘this’ when it wasn’t static, I’m not sure why."  In addition to changing the `Modifiers` property, you should show how you are trying to access the controls from a different class; you're obviously doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The following warning message can be found in `Form1.Designer.cs`

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
 /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
 /// </summary>
```

It's not necessary to modify any code in "Form1.Designer.cs" or to change the "Modifiers" property for Form1. In order to make TextBox values accessible, use a property value for each one:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestProj
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return tbFirstName.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                tbFirstName.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return tbLastName.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                tbLastName.Text = value;
            }
        }
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: If you want to get the values but don't want the values to be set using the properties, then remove the "set" code. So you'd have:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return tbFirstName.Text;
    }
}

public string LastName
{
    get
    {
        return tbLastName.Text;
    }
}
```